# C++ unordered_map default allocator

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, unordered-map

I have an abstract class (**parent**) and just created derived class (**child**) from it as below:

```
class parent {
public:
    virtual string print()=0;
};

template<class T>
class child: public parent{
private:
    unordered_map<string, parent*> children;
public:
    parent *&operator[](string name) {
        return children[name];
    }
    virtual string print(){
        //some jobs...
    }
}
```

ok. Now i used derived class like below:

```
child<string> a;
a["test"]->print();
```

and the problem shows out.

I think the problem is that unordered_map::[] operator creates an instance of **parent** class rather than **child** class that I want.

How can tell **unordered_map** to create new items as **child < string >**

Comment: Before you call `a["test"]->print();` you should add an object there, `a["test"] = new child<string>;`  Or inside the `operator[]` add `if (children.find(name) == children.end()) children[name] = new child<T>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unordered_map<std::string, parent *>::operator[]` won't create instances of *any* class, as its values are pointers, not class instances.  So if you use it to access a key that was not previously inserted in the map, it will default-initialize a pointer (which initializes it to nullptr) and store that in the map.

If you want any non-nullptr values in the map, you'll need to store them there yourself.  You can do that in your `operator[]` function:

```
parent *&operator[](string name) {
    auto &rv = children[name];
    if (!rv) rv = new child<T>;
    return rv;
}
```

This has the danger of leaking memory if you ever overwrite any of these pointers that are returned by reference, plus you need to free them all in the destructor.  You can avoid the former problem by returning a `parent *` instead of a `parent *&`,  or by using `std::unique_ptr<parent>` in the map and returning a `std::unique_ptr<parent> &` here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` and you do the following operations:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;
std::cout << m["hello"];
std::cout << m["key1"];
```

The above program will not produce any kind of warning or error. In fact, it will output `00`. Two zeroes. So, what is happening here?

`unordered_map` or `map` `operator[]` *inserts* a value in case the key does not exist. This is one of the biggest source of unintentional bugs in C++. In the case above `"hello"` or `"key1"` did not exist, so they were created in-place with the `value` default initialized to `0`.

#### How to solve your issue?

Always make sure before using the `operator[]` whether the value you are trying to access even exists or not. In fact, it is just better to use the `.at()` member function if you want to perform a read.

Fixed code:

```cpp
child<string> a;
a["test"] = new child<string>;
a["test"]->print();
```

You can further prevent this behaviour by changing your `operator[]` function:

```
    parent *&operator[](string name) {
        if (children.find(name) == children.end()) // does it exist?
            children[name] = new child<T>; // if it doesn't, create a new one.
        return children[name];
    }
```